# Load bitmap error

Tags: windows-mobile

```
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
  { 
      base.OnPaint(e); 
      Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\test.bmp"); 
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0); 
  }
```

I tried the above code but an error saying could not find part of the path is shown in the line

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\test.bmp");
```

what could be the error?

Comment: Is the BMP file located on the device? Or are you trying to load a bitmap that is located on your desktop?
The answers below suggest that you should tell whether you copied the bitmap to the device and where in the device you put it.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a .Net Compact Framework application (as suggested by the `windows-mobile` tag), then there is no such thing as `C:\test.bmp` on a WinMo device.  Try `"\\test.bmp"`, assuming that you actually have a file named "test.bmp" at the root level of your device.

Comment: i am new to windows mobile so i dont know much abut the device. Can you please give me a little detailed explanation, how to solve the error

Comment: You solve the error by putting the actual path to your file.  It might be where your app is, it might be somewhere else.  Only you can tell where that is.

Comment: @Timmi: on a WinMo device, paths start with just a backslash, so if you have your Bitmap file in the Windows folder, the path would be `\Windows\test.bmp`. You can't access files on your PC from your WinMo device (at least not easily), so you need to first copy `test.bmp` from your PC onto the device somewhere.  ActiveSync will let you do this on a pre-Vista computer, and on Vista or later you should be able to just browse to your attached device.

Comment: @Timmi: an easier way, however, would be to load the bitmap file into an invisible PictureBox on your form in the designer (by setting its Image property), and then change your code to `e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, 0, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `"C:\\test.bmp"`.  Note the double backslash!

You can also use this string literal notation: `@"C:\test.bmp"`

Comment: Wrong.  CE has no concept of drives.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a high resolution image? which you are trying to load,